# JSONPath expression to get an object from an array based on condition

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

Given JSON structure

```
{
  "total_institutions": 2,
  "count_by_institution": [
    {
      "institution": {
        "id": "03629",
        "name": "institutiona03629"
      },
      "total_branches": 5
    },
    {
      "institution": {
        "id": "03659",
        "name": "institutiona03659"
      },
      "total_branches": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I am new to JSon Path. I would need a JSONPath expression to get institution object that has name equal to institutiona03659. So, given the example above, the result should be

```
{
  "institution": {
    "id": "03629",
    "name": "institutiona03629"
  },
  "total_branches": 5
}
```

Comment: what would be logic to pick that specific record over other record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$..[?(@.institution.name == 'institutiona03659')]
```

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [JsonPath Functions](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-path-extractor-jmeter)